# Want to sum fee in query month wise

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-query-syntax

```
var TotalFee = (from item in _dbEntities.MonthlyFees
                               where item.Year == DateTime.Now.Year &&
                               item.FeeStatus == true
                               select item).GroupBy(x =>x.MonthID);//.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => int.Parse(x));
```

I want to sum Column "Fee" which is nvarchar type and group it by MonthID

Comment: Why `Fee` column is of type "nvarchar" ? That's the first problem.

Comment: yes that is a drawback but imagine it is type of int than what would be the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look to this example

```
var feesDictionary = _dbEntities.MonthlyFees
            .Where(x => x.Year.Equals(DateTime.Now.Year) && x.FeeStatus)
            .GroupBy(x => x.MonthID)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => Convert.ToDouble(y.Fee)));
```

The keys are identifiers of months and values - sums of fee for appropriate month.